# PHP: How do I get the string indexes of a preg_match_all?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

let's say I have two regexp's,

```
/eat (apple|pear)/
/I like/
```

and text

```
"I like to eat apples on a rainy day, but on sunny days, I like to eat pears."
```

What I want is to get the following indexes with preg_match:

```
match: 0,5 (I like)
match: 10,19 (eat apples)
match: 57,62 (I like)
match: 67,75 (eat pears)
```

Is there any way to get these indexes using preg_match_all without looping through the text every single time?

**EDIT: SOLUTION** PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE !

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can try `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag for [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$subject="I like to eat apples on a rainy day, but on sunny days, I like to eat pears.";
$pattern = '/eat (apple|pear)/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
print_r($matches);
```

Output

```
$ php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => eat apple
            [1] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => 14
        )

)
```

Comment: Works with preg_match_all() as well :D

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that if you use `preg_match`, and a group isn't matched then not an array will be returned, but an empty string. You can use [T-Regx](https://github.com/Danon/T-Regx#callback-for-the-first-match) and use cleaner API:

```
$o = pattern('eat (apple|pear)')->match($text)->offsets()->all();
$o // [10, 14]
```

Or if you want some more advanced matches

```
pattern('eat (apple|pear)')
  ->match($text)
  ->iterate(function (Match $m) {
      $m->text();   // your fruit here
      $m->offset(); // your offset here
  });
```