# Preg match a string to find all encounters of -> using regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I'm having a small technical difficulty with a regular expression, I'm trying to look at a string, let's say we have this string:

```
$string = "error->400";
```

And another string:

```
$string = "error->debug->warning";
```

As an example, I'm basically trying to do a `preg_match()` that returns true on any instances of `->` within it.

This is my attempt but I don't understand why it doesn't work:

```
preg_match("/^[->]*$/", $string);
```

Is there a general rule for custom characters that i'm generally missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, `^[->]*$` matches any number of "-" or ">" characters, from the beginning to end.  You must use a group, not a character class, and anchors are not necessary. Use this to check if "->" is present in the `$string`:

```
 preg_match("/(->)/", $string);
```

Have a look at the [example](https://regex101.com/r/iZ7tO4/1).

Comment: Ah I see, so simple but that's it. Thank you very much. 
I like that regex tool, is their actually a way to get the indexes of the -> easily? so what position in the string they start and end.

Comment: So something like preg_match("/\([^\}]+\)/", $string) would get everything within ( ) ?is their a way to limit it to just one result?

Comment: @Matthew: to get indexes, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451915/php-how-do-i-get-the-string-indexes-of-a-preg-match-all post. As for `/([^\}]+)/`,  it will match any character other than `}` 1 or more number of times (greedy) and hold the whole match in Group 1.

Comment: So i guess if you wanted to get the first occurance you would do something like preg_match("/(->)/", $string, $output); and then just get $output[0] or is there a way to limit the regex to the first occurance?

Comment: @Matthew: To get the first occurrence, you could use `^.*?\K->(?=.*$)` regex. See example at https://regex101.com/r/iZ7tO4/2.